# How to add login via Twitter functionality with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-login

I read the documentation on https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/twitter.html. I downloaded and added the two files as it says in the documentation. I also imported Accounts at the beginning of the files, so Xcode builds successfully. Then I copied the exact code in the documentation to my twitterLogin IBAction, and set my Twitter API Key and Firebase base reference.

The problem is that when I click on my twitter login button, nothing happens. (It used to say no twitter accounts, then I set my account in the Settings.) I even put print statements in any if-else case but none of them prints. So is there any suggestions for making Twitter login work? I don't think Firebase is missing anything. But please give some suggestions on how to figure out the issue at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. The 'funny' solution was to add an equal sign to the condition

> if accounts.count > 1

For anyone who is not lucky enough to notice that the sample code in the Firebase documentation is weirdly working only for users that have 'more' than 1 twitter account signed in the device, I believe this answer would help to save some time.

I also think that this sample code is misleading.(may be something that shouldn't be the default case in the sample code)

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that you have Enabled Twitter Authentication in your Firebase Dashboard, and that the apiKey in your project matches the one that is in your Dashboard.

[image: Firebase Dashboard]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said, I solved the issue myself. My answer is below. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently found some pretty good stuff on exactly this topic may it can help someone:

https://medium.com/reversebits/twitter-authentication-in-firebase-for-android-51d1460dc6a9#.strjpm90r